# O componente referenciado "System.Core" não foi encontrado?

Tags: c#

O componente referenciado "System.Core" não foi encontrado?

Estou com este erro como posso resolver?

http://prntscr.com/a37caw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A library `System.Core` não está referenciada no seu projeto, convém tentar uma das tentativas abaixo, todas estão na página de propriedades do projeto (como vou lá?)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Método 1

Vamos alterar o *Framework Target* do seu projeto, vá na guia *Application* e altere o que está em `Target Framework` para o maior:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Método 2

Referencie manualmente a biblioteca *System.Core* no seu projeto. Vá na guia *References* e clique no botão *Add*.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Selecione na guia *Assemblies > Framework* as opções *System* e *System.Core* e então clique no *OK*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Método 3

Remova a assembly `System.Core` e tente executar seu projeto sem ela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado funcionou o método 1 :)

Answer (score -2):

Infelizmente não existe solução, o namespace `System.Core` só está disponível a partir da versão `3.5` do framework, ou você faz upgrade para a versão 3.5 ou você terá que prover outros meios de fazer o que pretendia.

Comment: Posso saber o motivo das negativações? visto que tenho certeza de que minha informação precede.